# How can View data be different from normal select?

Tags: sql-server, select, view, union

I am facing  a weird situation which seems to be a bug !

I have a view (let's say vwMyview) which contains 3 select from same tables that are UNIONed together:

```
SELECT c.*, r.ToNodeTitle, r.ToNodeID, r.ActivityDate FROM MYBB.[dbo].[ExContract] c inner join vwNodeStatus r on c.requestid = r.RequestID  where r.ToNodeID = 88 and r.statuscode in (0,1) 
UNION
SELECT c.*, r.ToNodeTitle, r.ToNodeID, r.ActivityDate FROM MYBB.[dbo].[ExContract] c inner join vwNodeStatus r on c.requestid = r.RequestID  where r.ToNodeID = 89 and r.statuscode in (0,1) 
UNION
SELECT c.*, r.ToNodeTitle, r.ToNodeID, r.ActivityDate FROM MYBB.[dbo].[ExContract] c inner join vwNodeStatus r on c.requestid = r.RequestID  where r.ToNodeID = 90 and r.statuscode = 7
```

***(I know there are better ways to create this view)***

The problem is that the result of above query is different from the result of simply Select  from the view.
When I select from view the content of ToNodeID is filled with ToNodeTitle data.

Does anyone knows in what condition this can happen ?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] that includes sample data as ddl+dml, and sample data.

Comment: I dropped and create view again and the problem went away.

Comment: Well, in that case, please consider deleting the question is the problem can't be reproduced.

Comment: Don't use `*` in view declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens sometimes, in particular when you make DDL changes in the underlying objects from which the view takes its data. In order to mitigate this, you can either issue an `alter view` statement with the same code as it was before, or use `sys.sp_refreshview` stored procedure.

Same issue can happen with other code modules as well; in this case, use `sys.sp_refreshsqlmodule` system procedure.